# using Recyclerview in fragment and coroutines not work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, kotlin-coroutines

hi im using recyclerview in a fragment and coroutine, but recyclerview not update and is empty

this is my code that fetch data from web and i wrote that in OnCreateView

```
launch {
            val operation = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                Log.d("asdasdasd", "start")
                var doc: Document = Jsoup.connect("http://5743.zanjan.medu.ir").timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).ignoreHttpErrors(true).get()
                val table: Elements = doc.select("table[class=\"table table-striped table-hover\"]")
                for (myTable in table) {
                    val rows: Elements = myTable.select("tr")
                    for (i in 1 until rows.size) {
                        val row: Element = rows.get(i)
                        val cols: Elements = row.select("td")
                        val href: Elements = row.select("a")
                        val strhref: String = href.attr("href")
                        itemsData.add(CircularModel(cols.get(2).text(),strhref,"2019",""))
                    }
                }
            }
            operation.await() // wait for result of I/O operation without blocking the main thread

            // update views
            activity?.runOnUiThread{
                adapter = CircularAdapter(itemsData, this@CircularFragment)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                rc.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
```

i checked and itemsData isnt empty but i dont know why recyclerview not updated

Comment: the issue is in the adapter, post the adapter code and have you added the layout manager?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh no i didnt set layout manager, but my app work with this codes in activity, but in fragment not work

Comment: Why are you assigning adapter to recyclerview after calling **notifyDataSetChanged**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` instead of `activity?.runOnUiThread{` syntax to access Main thread from the coroutine

Answer (score -1):

Try to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting adapter to your Recycler